# How to get background color of XSSFSimpleShape object?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Does POI-Framwork support to get background color of a XSSFSimpleShape object? I looked around this class but I couldn't find the way to get its background?
Here is my code:

```
XSSFSimpleShape simpleObj = ...
simpleObj.getCTShape().getSpPr()... get some things named color here
simpleObj.getCTShape().getStyle().getFillRef()... get some things named colors here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the opposite of a trivial task. You are on the right way with [CTShapeProperties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTShapeProperties.java#CTShapeProperties). The next step is [CTSolidColorFillProperties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTSolidColorFillProperties.java#CTSolidColorFillProperties) and as long we will find a [CTSRgbColor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTSRgbColor.java#CTSRgbColor) all things will be easy because this is simply `RGB`. But there are much more possible kinds of color types as you see.

One possible color type which `Excel` is often using is [CTSchemeColor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTSchemeColor.java#CTSchemeColor). This color is a theme color from `ThemesTable` but possibly additional determined by given luminescence changing from `lumMod` and `lumOff`.

Example XML:

```
<a:solidFill>
 <a:schemeClr val="accent4">
  <a:lumMod val="60000"/>
  <a:lumOff val="40000"/>
 </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

Problem with this is that those luminescence changings are made in [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). `Java`s `java.awt.Color` is only supporting `HSB` (aka `HSV`) but not `HSL`. So we need additional code for supporting `HSL`. In my example I have used the code from [Rob Camick](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/).

So knowing that all we can do the following:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSimpleShape;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTShape;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTShapeProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTSolidColorFillProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STSchemeColorVal;

import java.awt.Color;

class ReadExcelShapeFillColors {

 //two methods for dealing with the HSL color model
 //helper method HueToRGB, see below
 private static float HueToRGB(float p, float q, float h) {
  if (h < 0) h += 1;
  if (h > 1 ) h -= 1;
  if (6 * h < 1) {
   return p + ((q - p) * 6 * h);
  }
  if (2 * h < 1 ) {
   return  q;
  }
  if (3 * h < 2) {
   return p + ( (q - p) * 6 * ((2.0f / 3.0f) - h) );
  }
  return p;
 }

 //get a new Color changed by given luminescence from lumMod and lumOff
 private static Color getColorLumModandOff(Color color, int lumMod, int lumOff) {
  float[] rgb = color.getRGBColorComponents( null );
  float r = rgb[0];
  float g = rgb[1];
  float b = rgb[2];
  float min = Math.min(r, Math.min(g, b));
  float max = Math.max(r, Math.max(g, b));

  float h = 0;
  if (max == min) h = 0;
  else if (max == r) h = ((60 * (g - b) / (max - min)) + 360) % 360;
  else if (max == g) h = (60 * (b - r) / (max - min)) + 120;
  else if (max == b) h = (60 * (r - g) / (max - min)) + 240;

  float l = (max + min) / 2;
  l = l * (float)lumMod/100000f + (float)lumOff/100000f;

  float s = 0;
  if (max == min) s = 0;
  else if (l <= .5f) s = (max - min) / (max + min);
  else s = (max - min) / (2 - max - min);

  h = h % 360.0f;
  h /= 360f;

  float q = 0;
  if (l < 0.5) q = l * (1 + s);
  else q = (l + s) - (s * l);
  float p = 2 * l - q;
  r = Math.max(0, HueToRGB(p, q, h + (1.0f / 3.0f)));
  g = Math.max(0, HueToRGB(p, q, h));
  b = Math.max(0, HueToRGB(p, q, h - (1.0f / 3.0f)));

  r = Math.min(r, 1.0f);
  g = Math.min(g, 1.0f);
  b = Math.min(b, 1.0f);

  return new Color(r, g, b, 1.0f);
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("ExcelWithSimpleShape.xlsx");

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Drawing<? extends Shape> drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();

  for (Shape shape : drawing) {

   System.out.println(shape.getClass());
   System.out.println(shape.getShapeName() + "_________________");

   if (shape instanceof XSSFSimpleShape) { //we have a XSSFSimpleShape

    XSSFWorkbook xssfworkbook = (XSSFWorkbook)workbook;
    ThemesTable themesTable = xssfworkbook.getTheme();

    XSSFSimpleShape xssfSimpleShape = (XSSFSimpleShape)shape;

    CTShape ctShape = xssfSimpleShape.getCTShape();
    CTShapeProperties ctShapeProperties = ctShape.getSpPr();

    byte[] bRGB;

    if (ctShapeProperties.isSetSolidFill()) { //we have a solid fill defined
     CTSolidColorFillProperties ctSolidColorFillProperties = ctShapeProperties.getSolidFill();

     if (ctSolidColorFillProperties.isSetSrgbClr()) { //we have a explicit given RGB color
      bRGB = ctSolidColorFillProperties.getSrgbClr().getVal();
      System.out.println((bRGB[0]&0xFF)+", "+(bRGB[1]&0xFF)+", "+(bRGB[2]&0xFF));
      Color color = new Color(bRGB[0]&0xFF, bRGB[1]&0xFF, bRGB[2]&0xFF);
      System.out.println("explicit given RGB color: " + color);

     } else if (ctSolidColorFillProperties.isSetSchemeClr()) { //we have a scheme color defined in ThemesTable
      int iThemeColorIdx = ctSolidColorFillProperties.getSchemeClr().getVal().intValue()-1;
      System.out.println("theme color index: " + iThemeColorIdx);

      //get luminescence definition
      int lumMod = 100000;
      int lumOff = 0;
      if (ctSolidColorFillProperties.getSchemeClr().getLumModList().size() > 0)
       lumMod = ctSolidColorFillProperties.getSchemeClr().getLumModList().get(0).getVal();
      if (ctSolidColorFillProperties.getSchemeClr().getLumOffList().size() > 0)
       lumOff = ctSolidColorFillProperties.getSchemeClr().getLumOffList().get(0).getVal();
      System.out.println("lumMod: " + lumMod);
      System.out.println("lumOff: " + lumOff);

      XSSFColor xssfColor = themesTable.getThemeColor(iThemeColorIdx);
      bRGB = xssfColor.getRGB(); //RGB color from ThemesTable
      System.out.println((bRGB[0]&0xFF)+", "+(bRGB[1]&0xFF)+", "+(bRGB[2]&0xFF));
      Color color = new Color(bRGB[0]&0xFF, bRGB[1]&0xFF, bRGB[2]&0xFF);

      color = getColorLumModandOff(color, lumMod, lumOff); //Color changed by given lumMod and lumOff

      System.out.println("scheme color: " + color);
     }
    } else { //we have accent1 scheme color as fill color
      XSSFColor xssfColor = themesTable.getThemeColor(STSchemeColorVal.INT_ACCENT_1-1);
      bRGB = xssfColor.getRGB();
      System.out.println((bRGB[0]&0xFF)+", "+(bRGB[1]&0xFF)+", "+(bRGB[2]&0xFF));
      Color color = new Color(bRGB[0]&0xFF, bRGB[1]&0xFF, bRGB[2]&0xFF);
      System.out.println("accent1 scheme color: " + color);
    }
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

This code will get the fill colors of all shapes from first sheet of the `XSSFWorkbook` file which are `instanceof XSSFSimpleShape` as long as they are given by solid fill and are either `CTSRgbColor` or `CTSchemeColor`.